# mountain lion server - web services wiki only work on host computer

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app

We have macmini with os x mountain lion server app installed. The web services and wiki only work on the host machine, not on any of the other computers on the network, using network users.
 When we set up the server app, the modem/router failed and we were unable to set the ip address of our server until we sorted our router out, which took a while. In the meantime in our excitement we tried to set up web services / wiki etc.. So I think that may have caused the issue.
Any ideas what we can do to fix this?
what direction to go?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to post this as an answer instead of a comment; I don't have enough Reputation here to comment.

1. Can you ping the server from another host?
2. If you can ping, try firing up a terminal with `tail -f /Library/Logs/wikid/error.log` and see what happens when someone tries to access the wiki service - that'll give you something to work with

Alternative to `tail`, use `Console.app` from your `/Applications/Utilities` folder